Problem with Selenium Chrome driver in Linux published in AWS ElasticBeanstalk
I have a problem publishing my .NET application with Selenium in an AWS ElasticBeanstalk environment.
When I upload the application it gives an error in one place and does not run Chrome as the application runs.
I have already installed the chrome driver and chrome via command, but I have not been successful yet.Log of ElasticBeanstalk
When i included a chromedriver path
enter image description here
my error is
Chrome error
Thanks a lot if help me
Execute a chrome and selenium to get informations of website
